# User cannot suggest edits to this question.

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I often will suggest formatting edits to questions where the math is not formatted well. On occasion, I'll receive the message that the user cannot suggest edits to this question. Is it me or the question that's the difficulty?

Edit:
I think what's happening is this. On the main interface, the edit button is greyed out when there's an edit in process. Perhaps not so on the mobile site?

Comment: Can you recall what the exact error message said? Note that suggested edits must alter at least six characters of the body of a post.

Comment: "User cannot suggest edits to this question." It definitely wasn't the six character thing. Another edit posted shortly thereafter. I think on the mobile site, the edit box opens, but it doesn't allow me to submit if there's another edit in progress.

Comment: Found something related on meta.SE: [I can't suggest edits from the mobile app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257137).

Comment: Same thing happened to me with the app. Same error but after I tried again I was able to suggest.

Comment: I changed the edit message a bit and it worked.